# Does modprobe.d blacklist always need the prefix "blacklist-"?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

In the german Ubuntu-Wiki it says, that the name of a blacklist in modprobe.d can be chosen as prefered but the filename has to begin with "blacklist-". Is that right? Because in a forum I read a blacklist was named "broadcom.conf". Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Red Hat documentation it would appear the name of the file containing "blacklist" is optional.

[36.3.2. Blacklisting a driver](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/rescuemode_drivers-blacklisting.html), specifically step 6:

> 6)  Create a new file under `/etc/modprobe.d/` that contains the command blacklist name_of_driver. Give the file a descriptive name that will help you find it in future, and use the filename extension .conf. For example, to continue to blacklist the driver foobar when the root device is mounted, run:
>
> ```
> $ echo "blacklist foobar" >> /mnt/sysimage/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-foobar.conf
> ```

Looking through several of my systems I could find no example where the command `blacklist` was contained in a file other than ones named `blacklist-....`.

I'd try it but I'd expect it to work in any file name. The command `blacklist ...` would seem to be what's important.

Answer (score 1):

The file name in `/etc/modprobe.d/` has to end with the `.conf` extension.

The content of the file, that is the directive to not load a certain module, has to use the keyword `blacklist`, like so:

```
less /etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth.conf
blacklist btusb
blacklist bluetooth
```

See the [Archwiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Blacklisting) for details.